# Are air conditioning compressor for Toyota different in US vs Europe?

Tags: toyota, ac, compatibility

The air conditioning compressor of my car ('09 Toyota Yaris, 1.33L engine, EU, VNK KH963) is broken and I'm looking for a replacement. Unfortunately the original Toyota ones are very expensive and I'm looking for compatible compressors. The original Toyota part number for the compressor is 88310-0D320

Looking around there might be compatible options like the UAC CO 11078C A/C Compressor. On their website however, they only list American models (different engine sizes). Are A/C compressors anyway compatible between American or European models? Or are there other compatible A/C compressors available for my car?

Comment: have you looked on sites like eurocarparts?

Comment: I have, but there the compressor is still relatively expensive

Comment: I've pulled up images of each. It's really hard to tell if there are difference from pictures, especially when they only show one side of each compressor and the two images don't align. Considering how things work, I'd suggest you can go forward with about a 99%+ certainty the two are not the same.

Answer (score 3):

AC compressors are made by a separate company, not by the car maker. They have a label which lists the model code. Identify the compressor model, and then begin looking around for that very compressor.

To complicate things further, the same compressor model may feature different body and clutch configurations.

Let's take, as an example, a Sanden SD7H15. Sanden compressors feature, along with the model code, another code that identifies a certain body configuration. This particular compressor is used in a very large number of vehicles of different types so it necessarily needs to be suited for each vehicle.

You'll see with your own eyes that a SD7H15-7933 compressor's body and clutch arrangement is very different from the one of a SD7H15-4828, yet, internally, they're both the same compressor and they still pump the same volume of refrigerant around. The only different thing is the application.

That's the info you need to look for if you want to find a compressor for your car, though the labeling system may be different with other brands.

Perhaps, if you can, take a picture of your compressor's label (provided you haven't solved your problem yet), and post it here.

Comment: In the end, I did solve my problem and found a company in Germany that made compatible parts. Thanks for your help.